# How to know the size of image in UIImageView

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiimageview

I have imageView with some frame

```
imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0, 100, 100);
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

imageView.image = myImage;
```

*The question is* :

Is there any property or method in imageview to know the **result** size of the image after it's resizing (something like this : `imageView.image.size)`

(or should i calculate it myself using image size before and imageview frame)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to query the size of the scaled image, you have to calculate it yourself using the image size and the size constraints.